# How to do error handling and catching in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch

### Problem Sketch:

```
double& ComplexNumber::operator[](const unsigned index){
   if(index>1){
       std::cerr<<"Index out of bounds"<<std::endl;
   }else if(index==0){return x;
   }else if (index==1){return y;
   }
   return x;
}
```

This is just some dummy-code to show where it would occur.

### Question:

The idea here is what are we suppose to do when something occurs that isn't "welcome"?

Coming from Java we would throw an exception and the "return" would not be executed, and the "catch clause would handle accordingly.

But how does this work in C++?
In the code above I am returning `x` cause it needs a `double&`. But this will corrupt the code that made the call to this function.

Comment: You can throw an exception in `C++` too. You can throw [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

Comment: Just use [`throw std::out_of_range()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception. What's the problem??

Comment: And how are we supose to catch em ?

Comment: @KoenDemonie With a try-catch block.

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to c++. trying to learn the kinks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less the same reasoning applies as in java, throw an exception unless you need to interface with legacy/non C++ code.

```
#include<stdexcept>

double& ComplexNumber::operator[](const unsigned index){
   if(index>1){
       throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds");
   }

   if(index==0){
       return x;
   }
   return y;
}
```

As a side point if you want to bring all the exception handling habits from java, bear in mind that there is no `finally` clause in C++. Use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) paradigm in order to ensure the cleanup happens: this will lead to a much cleaner and safer code in the end.

Other than that, throw by value, catch by reference, rethrow by writing:

```
try {
    // ComplexNumber cmplx defined somewhere
    cmplx[2];
} catch (std::out_of_range& ex) {
    // ...
    throw;
}
```

And you are good to go for the beginning, as long as you take your time to learn the reasons behind these rules of thumb at some point.

Comment: I would prefer `return index == 0 ? x : y;`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would probably write, but it is often good to keep examples simple. I've actually confused quite a few people with ternaries in the past :)